# Angular 6 - Rxjs Subscribe to the last events in QueryList changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am trying to solve a use case of an app I am developing with **Angular 6.x** and **Rxjs 6.x**

It may be quite simple but I am not able to solve....
Just to summarize I have some Components which I subscribe in the AfterViewInit Cycle and then I would need to execute only the last emit every time the observable is dispatched or emitted

```
 @ViewChildren(XComponent)
  xChilds: QueryList<XComponent>;

a ==> ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.xChilds.changes.pipe(
                ................ //I SHOULD PUT SOMETHING TO GET THE LAST VALUE
        ).subscribe(xChilds => {
          debugger;
          ------------------
```

*The diagram would be like this*

```
a)      >--A--A--A--A|
RESULT) >-----------A|
```

So my approach at the very first time was using operators like **TAKE(1)**, **FIRST()** or **LAST()** and it is working

The point is that latter when I receive more events they don't fire or trigger again......

*And the diagram would be like this*

```
a)      >--A--A--A--A .......NOTHING HAPPENS.......... --A--A--A--A|
RESULT) >-----------A............................ ------------- NOTHING
```

Is like operators first etc unsubscribe after the first sequence

I am sure there should be an operator to achieve **what I want**.

```
a)      >--A--A--A--A....NOTHING HAPPENS....--A--A--A--A|
RESULT) >-----------A.......................-----------A|
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Did you try using `debounceTime` operator?

Comment: have you tried `withLatestForm` operator of rxjs?

Comment: That doesn't make sense at all. How would Rx know what's your `|` in a diagram?

Comment: There's a problem in your diagram so you'll never get the diagram you expect. One Observable chain can emit only one `complete` notification but in your diagram you expect it multiple times. The source Observable `this.xChilds.changes` won't emit multiple `complete` notifications.

Comment: @ritaj why it doesn't make any sense???? I would edit removing it

Comment: Observables either emit or complete. There is no third option ‘|‘. Can you explain ‘|‘ in words?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't really care about symbols...I mean I think what I explain is quite understandable if you cannot help me is ok I appreciate anyway...But I don't want to focus the question in this '|'

Comment: It's not understandable and without a better explanation no one will be able to help you because it's impossible to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski Thanks I have achieved with this operator, although I haven't understand why something like distinctUntilChanged, first or last! Thanks!